# ¿Por qué este cursor de SQL SERVER siempre me devuelve un registro?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

Tengo un cursor en `SQL SERVER` que solo toma el primer registro de la consulta inicial y no sé la razón.

Partimos de esta situación:

Tenemos dos tablas:

- Una de operaciones, `OPERATION`, que almacena los datos de cada operación (*facturas, albaranes, pedidos...*);
- Otra de movimientos, `MOVEMENT`, que son las líneas de las operaciones.

Una operación se identifica por el campo `OPENUMBER`, aunque también es habitual buscar por `OPEDOCNUMBER`.

Un movimiento se identifica por `MOVNUMBER`.

`OPERATION` y `MOVEMENT` se relacionan por `OPENUMBER` y `MOVNUMBER`.

Una factura puede estar formada por varios albaranes. Tanto los albaranes como las facturas se guardan en `OPERATION`.

Queremos sacar, a partir del número de documento de una factura, toda la información de sus albaranes.

Existe un campo de `MOVEMENT`, `MOVPREVIOUS`, que indica de qué albarán proviene la línea. Esto lleva al `OPEDOCNUMBER` del albarán, no `OPENUMBER`.

Cuando declaro el cursor, la consulta debe ser:

```
SELECT DISTINCT([.MOVPREVIOUS]) 
    FROM [MOVEMENT.] WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE [.MOVPREVIOUS] <> '' 
     AND [.MOVNUMBER] = (SELECT [.OPENUMBER] 
       FROM [OPERATION.] WITH(NOLOCK) 
         WHERE [.OPEDOCNUMBER] = 'FE-005/21-');
```

Ya tengo todos los `OPEDOCNUMBER` de albaranes que hay en la factura del *WHERE*.

Y ahora es, dentro de este cursor, sacar todo (*) de cada albarán.
El código completo es este:

```
DECLARE @OPEDOCNUMBER1 CHARACTER(10)
DECLARE @ALBARAN AS CHARACTER(10)
DECLARE ALBARANES CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT([.MOVPREVIOUS]) FROM [MOVEMENT.] WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE [.MOVPREVIOUS] <> '' AND [.MOVNUMBER] = (SELECT [.OPENUMBER] FROM [OPERATION.] WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE [.OPEDOCNUMBER] = 'FE-005/21-')
OPEN ALBARANES
FETCH NEXT FROM ALBARANES
INTO @ALBARAN
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @OPEDOCNUMBER1 = @ALBARAN
        SELECT * FROM [OPERATION.] WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE [.OPEDOCNUMBER] = @OPEDOCNUMBER1
        FETCH NEXT FROM ALBARANES
        INTO @ALBARAN
    END
CLOSE ALBARANES
DEALLOCATE ALBARANES
```

Y me devuelve la información de solo uno de los albaranes. Solo la del primero que devuelve el primer select y no del resto.

Comment: No será que te está devolviendo varios conjuntos y solo visualizas uno, con algún tipo de herramienta cliente, ya que por cada vuelta del cursor hay una `Select.... `. Por otro lado, si vas a utilizar el hint `with (Nolock)`, independientemente de que sea el camino correcto, quizá es mejor utilizar  [Set transaction isolation level read uncommitted](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Es posible que el procedimiento acabe en el primer `select`? Por qué no mejor haces un `select into` a una tabla temporal para cada resultado de la consulta dentro del `cursor` y luego, después de `cerrar` y `deallocate el cursor`, haces un `select` a esa temporal?